# Wordpress Ocean theme Logo

Tags: wordpress, redirect, themes, multilingual, polylang

WordPress, OceanWp theme.

Need a help. I have www.example.com site on default language, and www.example.com/second_language.
Both pages are main, for theirs own language. In that OceanWP theme, logo url have already redirect to DEFAULT language homepage. So maybe there is some easy way to get right redirects for both pages?

Sorry for my English and thanks for help.
Best regards

Comment: What plugin you using for multilingual support?

Comment: i will try to do it by polylang